# How to include theming the angular 2 material in webpack app. (JHipster)?

Tags: webpack, angular-material2

I am trying to import the angular material module into my app.
I have done the next things:
installed the angular material

```
yarn add @angular/material
```

included nesesary modules

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        DevizionSharedModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MdCardModule,
        MdTabsModule,
```

Included teh defoult styles in my vendor.scss 
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';

But it does not seems to work, what am i missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add material and hammerjs
   yarn add @angular/material hammerjs (yarn install if required)
   Material should be: "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.2" version
2. Import material module and hammerjs in every entity module
   "import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
   import 'hammerjs';"
   Add material module in imports array
3. Add the styles to vendor.scss. Add it before bootstrap
   @import 'node_modules/@angular/material/core/theming/prebuilt/deeppurple-amber.scss';

Comment: I assume you posted twice incorrectly. Choose your answer and delete the other one.

Answer (score 2):

import angular material module in your app.module.ts and add it in the imports metadata:

```
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
```

then add it to the imports metadata:

```
imports: [
  MaterialModule,
   .....
  ]
```

Also add this line in your global scss file :

```
@import '~@angular/material/core/theming/all-theme';
@include mat-core();
```

Also you may need to add this stylesheet in index.html to use the material icons in your app:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons'>
```